# CRUD firestore React function delete()

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud, delete-row

I am trying to do the delete function for a CRUD with React & Firestore, I already manage to eliminate it, the problem is the way I get the ID since it always deletes the record that is lower in the table.

function delete()

```js
const handleDelete = async(id) =>{
/* setData([]); */
   
console.log(id)
try {
  
   /* await db.collection('empleado').doc(id).delete(); */ 
  
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
  }
```

get ID

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  
db.collection('empleado')
.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) =>{ 
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
    setData(data => [ ...data,[doc.data().dleted,doc.data().tipoDoc,doc.data().doc,doc.data().lugarExp,doc.data().nombre,doc.data().direccion, doc.data().telefono,doc.data().email,doc.data().cargo,doc.data().rh,doc.data().eps,doc.data().tiempoPago,doc.data().sueldo]]);
  });
})

db.collection('empleado').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
  setId(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({id: doc.id})))
})
   
  },[]);
```

onClick function button parameter

```js
{
name: "Delete",
options: {
  filter: true,
  sort: false,
  empty: true,
  customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
    return (
      <button  onClick={ ()=>handleDelete(id) }>
        Delete
      </button>
    );
  }
}
  },
```

this is my console.log()

```js
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "48DIVsf7NLc5ux5vfH76"}
1: {id: "B3Jnpmmtipmi3IwvxKzs"}
2: {id: "cSPnc9lDpgvWNDXsXhfo"}
3: {id: "rLzJuLFfanXTSArA9fd2"}
length: 4
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

this happen when press button delete (any row button delete), i want upload a image of my table.

Component

```js
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import "../../../css/employee.css";
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import { db } from '../../../firebase';
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';

function Employee(){
  const [data,setData] = React.useState([]);
  const[id,setId]=React.useState('');
  const[dleted,setDleted]=React.useState('');
  
  const handleDelete = async(id) =>{
    /* setData([]); */
    console.log(id)
    try {
       /* await db.collection('empleado').doc(id).delete(); */ 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
      
    db.collection('empleado')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) =>{ 
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
        setData(data => [ ...data,[doc.data().tipoDoc,doc.data().doc,doc.data().lugarExp,doc.data().nombre,doc.data().direccion, doc.data().telefono,doc.data().email,doc.data().cargo,doc.data().rh,doc.data().eps,doc.data().tiempoPago,doc.data().sueldo]]);
      });
    })

    db.collection('empleado').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
      setId(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({id: doc.id, data:doc.data()})))
    })
   
  },[]);
  const columns =[{
    name: "Delete",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: false,
      empty: true,
      customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
        return (
          <button  onClick={ ()=>handleDelete(id)}> 
        Delete
      </button>
        );
      }
    }
  },
   "TIPO DOCUMENTO", "DOCUMENTO", "LUGAR EXPEDICION", "NOMBRE","DIRECCION","TELEFONO","EMAIL","CARGO","RH","EPS","TIEMPO SUELDO","SUELDO"];

 const options = {
   filterType: 'checkbox',
 };


  return(
    <div id="employ">

    <div><Dashboard /></div>
    
    <hr/>

<div style={{marginLeft:'18em'}}>
<MUIDataTable 
title={"EMPLEADOS"} 
data={data} 
columns={columns} 
options={options} 
/>

</div>

 


    </div>
  );
}
export default Employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button  onClick={ ()=>handleDelete(tableMeta.rowData[0])}> //you have to put the index of your id here
        Delete
      </button>
```

Comment: does not working, i think that the problem is when obtain the ID and i don't know how get only the current ID for row, check the update post, please.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO

COMPONENT Employee

```js
import React,{useEffect} from 'react';
import "../../../css/employee.css";
import Dashboard from '../Dashboard';
import { db } from '../../../firebase';

import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";

import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';

function Employee(){



  const [data,setData] = React.useState([]);

  const[id,setId]=React.useState('');
  const[dleted,setDleted]=React.useState('');

   const [tipoDoc, setTipoDoc] = React.useState('');
  const [doc, setDoc] = React.useState('');
  const [lugarExp, setLugarExp] = React.useState('');
  const [nombre, setNombre] = React.useState('');
  const [direccion, setDireccion] = React.useState('');
  const [telefono, setTelefono] = React.useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
  const [cargo, setCargo] = React.useState('');
  const [rh, setRh] = React.useState('');
  const [eps, setEps] = React.useState('');
  const [tiempoPago, setTiempoPago] = React.useState('');
  const [sueldo, setSueldo] = React.useState('');





  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    
    e?.preventDefault();
    setData([]);
    
    db.collection("empleado").add({
      tipoDoc: tipoDoc,
      doc: doc,
      lugarExp: lugarExp,
      nombre: nombre,
      direccion: direccion,
      telefono: telefono,
      email: email,
      cargo: cargo,
      rh:rh,
      eps:eps,
      tiempoPago:tiempoPago,
      sueldo:sueldo,
      
    }).then(() => {
      
    }).catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message)
    });
  }
 
  const handleDelete = async(id,index) =>{
     setData([]); 
    let parse = '';
    let parse2='';
    console.log(id);
    console.log(index);
    parse = parseInt(index);
    
     for (let i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
      if(i === parse ){
        const element = id[i];
        console.log("element",typeof(element))
        parse2 = element;
        console.log("B3Jnpmmtipmi3IwvxKzs"==parse2)
          await db.collection("empleado").doc(parse2).delete().then(() => {
          console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      });  
      }
     
    }
       
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
      
    db.collection('empleado')
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) =>{ 
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
        setData(data => [ ...data,[doc.data().tipoDoc,doc.data().doc,doc.data().lugarExp,doc.data().nombre,doc.data().direccion, doc.data().telefono,doc.data().email,doc.data().cargo,doc.data().rh,doc.data().eps,doc.data().tiempoPago,doc.data().sueldo]]);
      });
    })

    db.collection('empleado').onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
      setId(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => (doc.id)))
    })
   
  },[]);



  const columns =[{
    name: "Delete",
    options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: false,
      empty: true,
      customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
        return (
          <button  onClick={ ()=>handleDelete(id,`${tableMeta.rowIndex}`)}> 
        Delete
      </button>
        );
      }
    }
  },
  , "TIPO DOCUMENTO", "DOCUMENTO", "LUGAR EXPEDICION", "NOMBRE","DIRECCION","TELEFONO","EMAIL","CARGO","RH","EPS","TIEMPO SUELDO","SUELDO"];

 const options = {
   filterType: 'checkbox',
 };


  return(
    <div id="employ">

    <div><Dashboard /></div>
    
    <hr/>

<div style={{marginLeft:'18em'}}>
<MUIDataTable 
title={"EMPLEADOS"} 
data={data} 
columns={columns} 
options={options} 
/>

</div>

 <hr />
    <hr /><br /><br /><br/>
    <Form id="form-contact">
      <Row className="mb-3">

      <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
          <Form.Label>Tipo documento</Form.Label>
          <Form.Select defaultValue="-" value={tipoDoc} onChange={e => { setTipoDoc(e.target.value) }}>
            <option>-</option>
            <option>Tarjeta Identidad</option>
            <option>Cedula Ciudadania</option>
            <option>Cedula Extranjeria</option>
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
          <Form.Label>Documento</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" value={doc} onChange={e => { setDoc(e.target.value) }} placeholder="0000000" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Label>Lugar expedicion</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="text" value={lugarExp} onChange={e => { setLugarExp(e.target.value) }} placeholder="municipio/departamento" />
        </Form.Group>
      </Row>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress1">
        <Form.Label>Nombre</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="name" value={nombre} onChange={e => { setNombre(e.target.value) }} />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress2">
        <Form.Label>Direccion</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control placeholder="Cra - #" value={direccion} onChange={e => { setDireccion(e.target.value) }} />
      </Form.Group>

      <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>Telefono </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={telefono} onChange={e => { setTelefono(e.target.value) }} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>Email </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={email} onChange={e => { setEmail(e.target.value) }} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>Cargo </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={cargo} onChange={e => { setCargo(e.target.value) }} />
        </Form.Group>
        

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
          <Form.Label>RH</Form.Label>
          <Form.Select defaultValue="-" value={rh} onChange={e => { setRh(e.target.value) }}>
            <option>-</option>
            <option>A+</option>
            <option>AB+</option>
            <option>O+</option>
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>EPS </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={eps} onChange={e => { setEps(e.target.value) }} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>Tiempo pago </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={tiempoPago} onChange={e => { setTiempoPago(e.target.value) }} />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>Sueldo </Form.Label>
          <Form.Control value={sueldo} onChange={e => { setSueldo(e.target.value) }} />
        </Form.Group>
      </Row>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" id="formGridCheckbox" style={{textAlign:'left'}}>
        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Acepto términos del servicio y tratamiento de datos." />
      </Form.Group>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg"  onClick={()=>handleSubmit()} >Agregar</button>
      
   
    </Form>
<hr/>
<hr/> 


    </div>
  );
}
export default Employee;
```